# I got "unrecognized selector sent to instance" when trying to hide keyboard

Tags: ios

I have a textfield on cell on UITableView. In the UITableViewControoler, which I set it to be the delegate for textfield, I put the below method to hide keyboard

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {


    if (theTextField == self.nameTextField) {

       [theTextField resignFirstResponder];

    }
    return YES;
}
```

I could see that this method get invoked, but it crash when it reach resignFirstResponder with error "unrecognized selector sent to instance". i don't know why?

Comment: Add a trace like: `NSLog(@"theTextField: %@", [theTextField description]);` before calling `resignFirstResponder` and see what it outputs...

Comment: What is the full error message in the console, what message, that object is it being sent to. Is the cell still valid?

Comment: this is the full error log after adding log description: theTextField: <UITextField: 0x7bc9430; frame = (113 6; 182 31); text = 'Tom Jamesfg'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bc9030>>
2012-01-31 21:57:40.754 CastNear[1092:11603] -[SettingViewController nameTextFiled:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c80850
2012-01-31 21:57:40.755 CastNear[1092:11603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SettingViewController nameTextFiled:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c80850'
(

Comment: The error mentions `nameTextFiled` but the code in the question has `nameTextField`.  Are you referencing `nameTextFiled` somewhere?

Comment: Many Thanks.. Yes, it seems i did mistyping mistake, I removed all storyboared connection & I did it all over again and it works!! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a getter for your text field.  You must not have synthesized it or you misspelled the getter method.

Answer (score 1):

You may probe: set delegate of the text field and overwrite function:

```
theTextField.delegate = self;
```

...

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextFoeld *)textField {
.... here resign first responder, endEditinig
}
```

or/and hide kbd another way:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried to set this but I still getting same error, even when I used [self.view endEditing:YES];